# Subdomain redirection in Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla, subdomain

I have www.mydomain.com and subdomain gallery.domain.com
On www.mydomain.com have Joomla with menu:
Home | Offer | Gallery | Contact

Is it possible to connect this with my subdomain with links in that way?

> Home - www.mydomain.com 
>  Offer - www.mydomain.com/offer/ 
>   Gallery - gallery.mydomain.com 
>  Contact -
>   www.mydomain.com/contact/

All should have the same menu and template, only link of Gallery should be visible as subdomain.

I tried "Virtual Domains" extension but it changes all my links, so when I am at Gallery, all links in my menu are like gallery.mydomain.com/contact/ instead www.mydomain.com/contact/

Answer (score 0):

Joomla is generally displaying relative url's, which is why your menu is displaying links relative to the gallery subdomain when you are at this site. If the menu links are your only problem, you could prevent this by overriding mod_menu in your template, adding http://yourdomain.com to all relative links.

Copy default_component.php from /mod_menu/tmpl to /templates/yourtemplate/html/mod_menu, and modify the urls as below:

```
// from around line 27
switch ($item->browserNav)
{
    default:
    case 0:
?><a <?php echo $class; ?>href="http://yourdomain.com<?php echo $item->flink; ?>" <?php echo $title; ?>><?php echo $linktype; ?></a><?php
        break;
    case 1:
        // _blank
?><a <?php echo $class; ?>href="http://yourdomain.com<?php echo $item->flink; ?>" target="_blank" <?php echo $title; ?>><?php echo $linktype; ?></a><?php
        break;
    case 2:
    // Use JavaScript "window.open"
?><a <?php echo $class; ?>href="http://yourdomain.com<?php echo $item->flink; ?>" onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');return false;" <?php echo $title; ?>><?php echo $linktype; ?></a>
<?php
        break;
}
```

I believe this is the only file you'll need to override.

Comment: Hi, thanks but it doesn't work. I did as you wrote, clear the cache, even try browsing incognito. It is still not working.

Comment: Just nothing happened. Links stil are as subdomain (when I enter subdomain) or domain (when I am on domain)

Comment: OK, if you are going to get anywhere with this, you need to do some work yourself. Figure out if the override is working, by adding a die(); on top of the default_component.php - file, for example. If nothing happens now then the override is not working, means you did something wrong. Read the docs on overriding modules here https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Module_Layout_Overrides